# Is it possible to change particle color?

Tags: p5.js

is it possible to change the particle color to any color in mind?
Because i only get one color and i want to change it to make it more suitable for spring is there a way to configure the colors based on your taste following is my functions code:

```
function Particle() {
  this.pos = createVector(random(width), random(height));
  this.vel = createVector(0, 0);
  this.acc = createVector(0, 0);
  this.maxspeed = 4;
  this.h = 100;

  this.prevPos = this.pos.copy();

  this.update = function() {
    this.vel.add(this.acc);
    this.vel.limit(this.maxspeed);
    this.pos.add(this.vel);
    this.acc.mult(0);
  }

  this.follow = function(vectors) {
    var x = floor(this.pos.x / scl);
    var y = floor(this.pos.y / scl);
    var index = x + y * cols;
    var force = vectors[index];
    this.applyForce(force);
  }

  this.applyForce = function(force) {
    this.acc.add(force);
  }

  this.show = function() {
    strokeWeight(6);
    stroke(255, this.h, 10);
    this.h = this.h + 1;
    if (this.h > 255) {
      this.h = 100;
    }
    strokeWeight(8);
    line(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.prevPos.x, this.prevPos.y);
    this.updatePrev();
  }

  this.updatePrev = function() {
    this.prevPos.x = this.pos.x;
    this.prevPos.y = this.pos.y;
  }

  this.edges = function() {
    if (this.pos.x > width) {
      this.pos.x = 0;
      this.updatePrev();
    }
    if (this.pos.x < 0) {
      this.pos.x = width;
      this.updatePrev();
    }
    if (this.pos.y > height) {
      this.pos.y = 0;
      this.updatePrev();
    }
    if (this.pos.y < 0) {
      this.pos.y = height;
      this.updatePrev();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You should consider doing a little more research about the code in question before you make a post here. If your question can be readily answered by doing basic research it may be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `stroke(255, this.h, 10)` in the `show` function is what is determining the color of the line drawn by the `Particle` class in this case. It looks like it is cycling from red to yellow. The stroke function is [well documented](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/stroke). You can certainly use it to make the line drawn in this example any color you want. You can learn more about color in p5js on [p5js.org](https://p5js.org/learn/color.html).